# How to sort js file on meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two js file :

```
validate.js
login.js
```

login.js needs function in validate.js, so login.js must call after validate.js.
but in meteorjs i dont know how to sort it like that. because as i know all file js in client/ will be loaded. and this is the result :

```
login.js
validate.js
```

please help how to sort thid js file?

**update**
Okay i can sort js file now, but i cant call function from validate.js
this is my validate.js :

```
function firstValidator(){
    this.isTextValidate = {
        text : function(text){
            return true;
        },
        password: function(password){
            return true;
        },
        date: function(date){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my login.js

```
var isValid = new firstValidator();
Template.cust_login.events({
    'click button':function(){
        login();

    },
    'keyup input#inputUserLogin': function () {
         alert(isValid.isTextValidate.text("text"));
    },
    'keyup input#inputUserPassword': function () {

    }

});
```

and it error in :

```
var isValid = new firstValidator();
Uncaught ReferenceError: firstValidator is not defined
```

why this is happend? and how to solve this, so i can use firstValidator() in another js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor loads files in the same directory alphabetically. Files in deeper subdirectories are loaded first. Files in a `lib/` directory are loaded before everything else. Files named like `main.*` are loaded last. In your case I would put `validate.js` in `client/lib/`. If you want your validate file to be available on the client and the server, put it just in `lib/` instead.

Comment: thanks @Cuberto the problem finish, but new problem happend :(

Comment: Meteor wraps files in an IIFE. This means that variables defined with a function declaration or `var` don't get exported to the global scope. If you want to define a global function, you need to do it without `var` or a function declaration: `firstValidator = function() { /* ... */ };`. A more explicit alternative is to pass in the global variable directly: `(function( global ) { global.firstValidator = function() {}; }( this ));`